# Downgrading openssl is not possible in OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl

After upgraded brew in OSX it also updated the openssl older version to openssl1.1 but openssl@1.1 is not supporting the older versions for ruby of 2.3.x or older but I need to use older version is there a way so that I can downgrade my openssl or brew

I don't have older version of ssl I did the rvm install version.It installed the ruby version successfully.But when I did "bundle" I am getting the error "ssl not supported .. "
Up on this: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4006 I understood its not possible to install ruby older version less than 2.4 with openssl@1.1 by using rvm. I want to know is it possibe to downgrade openssl by using brew directly?? I have tried multiple ways it not worked??

Comment: You need to include specific and reproducible behavior. What are the exact steps you take, what errors do you receive when taking them, what are the specific versions of the OS, apps, libraries, etc.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the version is the problem?  First try:

```
brew info openssl
```

Follow the instructions to be sure.  If this doesn't resolve the problem, please add more info on what error's you are getting.